# Looking for help with an actual solution to a stepping-stone probability problem

Tags: probability

Back in college, I remember a professor giving us this question:

In front of you is an endless line of stepping stones. You flip a coin: on heads, you step forward one stone (onto Stone 1), and on tails, you step forward two stones (directly onto Stone 2). You repeat this process over and over again. What is the probability that you land on the 100th stone?

The solution he gave us was fairly conceptual. His explanation was that the solution was 2/3 since:

- Stones 1-97 don't matter, since flips from this point cannot end the game.
- On stone 98, flipping Heads sends you to Stone 99 (continuing the game) while flipping Tails sends you to stone 100, ending the game.
- On stone 99, flipping Heads sends you to Stone 100, ending the game. Flipping tails sends you to stone 101, ending the game in a "loss".
- Two of the possible ways to end the game result in a "win", and one results in a "loss", so the probability is, overall, 2/3 to land on the 100th stone.

Is there a more mathematical way to represent this? I feel like I'm either overlooking something simple or missing something entirely.

Thank you!

Comment: Personally, my intuition is too limited to grasp that the professor's conclusion is accurate.   From my perspective, it could be that your professor is wrong, or it could be that he is right, and I just can't see it.  From stone 97, it seems to me that your chances are better if your next step takes you to stone 98, rather than stone 99.  ...see next comment

Comment: @user2661923 I'm kind of in the same boat. Going farther and farther back, the probability changes each time; from Stone 98, I'm (mathematically) getting a probability of 75%; either Flipping Tails or flipping Heads-Heads.

But then from say, Stone 96, I'm getting ~68% from the following outcomes: HHHH, TT, HHT, HTH, or THH. I'm assuming that, going farther back, it might just average out?

Comment: If I was attacking this problem, and I wanted to **prove**, either that the professor is right, or that the professor is wrong, I would use recursion.  I would let $~S(k)~$ denote the probability of success, assuming that  there are exactly $~k~$ stones, rather than $~1000~$ stones.  Then,  I would manually calculate $~S(k)~$ for each $~k \in \{3,4,5\}.~$  Then, I would try to express $~S(k+2),~$ based on $~S(k+1),~$ and $~S(k).~$ Then, I would use this relationship to chart $~S(k)~$ for each $~k \in ~\{6,7,8,9,10\}.~$ ...see next comment

Comment: **Only then**, would I attempt to examine the data, stretch my intuition, and then form a conclusion.

Comment: Here is how I would approach it. Let $X_2,X_2,...$ be a sequence of iid random variables such that $$\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_1=2)=0.5$$ for each $n\geq 1$ take $E_n$ as the event $$E_n=\{X_1+\dots +X_k=n \text{ for some } k\}$$ If you take $a_n=\mathbb{P}(E_n)$ you can establish a recurrance relation for $a_n$ by condition on $X_1$ to compute $a_{100}$.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MathWonk, I had a bit of a breakthrough and think I found a solution. My thought process followed as such:

Consider that the only way to "win" is when the number of Heads (H) and two times the the number of Tails (T) sums to exactly 100. Therefore, possible solutions could include:

- H1, H2, H3...H100
- H1, H2, H3...H98, T1
- H1, H2, H3...H96, T1, T2
- ...
- H1,H2, T1, T2...T49
- T1, T2...T50

The probability of successfully flipping 100 Heads in a row is (1/2)^100, the probability of successfully flipping 98 Heads with 1 Tails is (1/2)^99, and so on, all the way down to the probability of flipping 50 Tails in a row, which is (1/2)^50. This can then be represented as:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{50} \frac{1}{2^{100-n}}$$

...where *n* represents the number of tails flipped. We then need to consider the fact that the placement of Tails flips can be spread out amongst the heads, represented by the combination $_{100-n}C_n$. For example: when looking at flipping 90 Heads and 5 Tails to reach the 100th Stone, we flip 95 coins but must select five of them to be Tails. This gives us the new summation:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{50} \frac{1}{2^{100-n}} \frac{(100-n)!}{(100-n-n)!n!}$$

Throwing this into Wolfram Alpha, I'm getting a decimal solution of:

- 0.6666666666666666666666666666669296203017403372684705761884275954...

Which matches what @MathWonk replied with; the answer of 2/3 is an incredibly close approximation, but technically misses out on a couple edge cases. Awesome! Thanks to everyone for the insight on figuring this out!

Comment: Nice job! If handy, could you also compute the case of  target value 10 rather than 100?

Answer (score 0):

The professor is almost right. The tiny correction needed to make that argument exactly correct would probably strike most people as tiresomely pedantic.  Below we explain why a correction is needed and make a rough estimate of the size of the correction.

Each game generates a sequence of heads and tails.  The running total of M heads and T tails can be plotted as a lattice path that moves up or right, in unit steps, as play progresses.   Because the coin is fair, all paths that have  the same total number of flips $M+N$ are equally likely to be reached at any stage of play (until the game terminates).
The question is: given that the game has terminated, what is the probability that the game ends in a win?

For simplicity let's play a short version of the game in which the goal is to hit the target value $M+2N =10$. The game terminates in a win if you hit 10, (black dots on the line) and terminates in a loss if you overshoot 10 on your last flip (red dots). The diagram below depicts all the possible  states of play just before the game terminates as blue dots. There are four clumps that each fit the format described by the professor. In each clump, you see two equally probable blue dots.
Thus you can check that in this clump, the odds of winning are 2:1.

This analysis breaks down in two edge cases that need special attention:
the path that ends at the black dot (0,5)  ends in a  Win. On the far right there is a path to a black dot at $(10,0)$ that is paired with a path to a red dot of equal probability, and for this pair the Win/Lose odds are 1:1.

[image]

Comment: Awesome display, thanks! This is an awesome way to help represent it. Thanks to this, I think I found another way to represent the solution. I'll add it as my own solution below if you're interested!